# Meaning of ⊗ applied to morphisms

Tags: category-theory

I think I understand what ⊗ means when applied to objects (such as M ⊗ M), but what does it mean when applied to morphisms (such as  η⊗1).  Is it just composition?

Comment: This question would probably be better suited to cs.stackexchange.com, or possibly math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the question is about [monoidal categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category) (for which https://math.stackexchange.com/ is the more appropriate site), `⊗ : C x C -> C` is a functor, and therefore has an action on objects and on morphisms. Given objects `X`, `X'`, `Y`, `Y'` in `C` and morphisms `x : X -> X'` and `y : Y -> Y'`, `x ⊗ y : X ⊗ Y -> X' ⊗ Y'` is a morphism in `C`.

Comment: Interesting.  So if η is a morphism that takes I to M (and we are talking about monoidal categories) and 1 is a morphism that takes M to M, then  η⊗ 1 is a morphism that takes I⊗ M to M⊗M.  That seems to fit with the diagrams.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: After reading a little more on the topic, I think that x ⊗ y would be X ⊗ Y -> X' ⊗ Y' (using the terms as defined in your example above).  This interpretation seems to fit better with most of the commutative diagrams.

Comment: @DMJ: you are completely right; I got the variable names mixed up – thanks! (Sorry, that must have been very confusing.)